# Windows Phone 7.8 Gmail app not working properly

Tags: 7.8, gmail, synchronization

I think ever since my Lumia 800 was upgraded to 7.8, the gmail app stopped working properly.
There are two things that don't work well:

- When searching for an email, it used to ask if I wanted to search online. This is not displayed anymore, I can only search in the mails downloaded to the phone;
- The sent items folder is not synchronizing. Even though I sent emails through gmail on my desktop, I can't see them in the phone even after synchronizing. Inbox is ok though.

Anyone has any idea to solve these problems?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: It's a native app, you can't uninstall it...

Comment: What do you mean by gmail app? Windows Phone does not have a "native gmail app" Are you referring to the built in email client?

Comment: Yes, the native mail app connected to gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been protocol changes by Google. If you have the latest phone update and Google mail is still not working as expected or as it worked previously, you might have to delete the Google account from your phone (`settings`, `email+accounts`, hold finger on the correct account, select `delete`) and then try adding the Google account again.

Your second problem might be related to settings in your Google mail inbox, as you can select which folders you want to have synchronized yourself. Open your Google mail client/tile (or the combined inbox that has your Google mail combined into it), go to `folders` menu item in the appbar, select to folder you want (in your case the sent folder of your Google account), select that and check the `sync this folder` or `don't sync this folder` menu item in the app bar. It might just be set to not sync (any more).